# Reactjs - How do I access data from a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Let me prefase this with I am a beginner, and have a component that holds data in the form:

```
const myList = ({products, add}) => {
  const component = products.map((product, index) => {
    return (
      <Item
        someData = {products[index].data}
        price = {products[index].price}
        ...
      />
    )
  })
  return (
    <div> {component} </div>
  )
}
```

In the main class of the project, I use the `myList` component to display the various items. In the render of the main, I can access by doing:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Items = [],
      basket[],
      ...
    }
...
  <myList
    products = {this.state.Items.filter((value, index, array) => {
      return this.state.Items[index].type === "some type"
    }
  }
...
}
```

I want to access a piece of data and display it. The filter above basically only displays an Item if it is of the correct type.

For example, each Item has a price associated with it, how would I be able to display the total of all the items selected?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to show the total item selected on the Main component. Then you need set logic inside some function in main. You need some increment variable which tracks the number of filters you set. For ex: if you click on red and blue colour then variable should also increment to 2. Then you can display on Main component.

Answer (score 0):

You have a great start going. You'll want to use the `Array.prototype.reduce()` method against your `products` filtered list. The syntax for a simple `reduce()` function looks like this:

```
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
```

So using your question about *total of all the items selected*, your call to `reduce()` would look like this:

```
const basketTotal = products.reduce(reducer);
```

Or, if you want to do this all in a single statement:

```
const basketTotal = products.reduce((a,c)=>a+c);
```

And that results in something like this:

```js
const products = [{price: 22, name: 'something'},{price: 22, name: 'somethingelse'}];

const basketTotal = products.reduce((a,c)=>a.price + c.price);

console.log(basketTotal); // outputs 44
```